# How to save login state in MSAL react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, msal.js, msal-react

My App.js file has thise router implemented

```
 <Router>
     <Route exact path="/"  render={(props) => <LoginPage/>} />
     <Route exact path="/Home" render={(props) => <Home />}/>
      <Route exact path="/create-request" render={(props) => <NewRequest />}/>
      <Route exact path="/my-requests" render={(props) => <MyRequests/>}/>
 </Router>
```

Login Page has the login button,but even after signing in from the login route ,on opening the /Home route, my isaunthenticated is showing false;
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can save the login state in localstorage or context after a successful login.

```
useEffect(() => {

   // get authentication here

   api.call('/auth')

     .then(data => {

       localStorage.setItem("authdata", JSON.stringify(data));

     

     })

    .catch(err => {

      setErr(err)

    })


 })
```

You can follow along with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react#sign-in-users) guide and login in the same way.

Thank you.